# BeautifulSoup not recognizing value from name atribute on select tag

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, namespaces, find, findall

I am trying to retrieve some dropdown lists options from a website, but i am not being able to make BeautifulSoup to read the value from name atribute on select tag.

My lists have this tags:

First list:

```
<select id="2" name="ComboEstado" onchange="Executar(this)" style="color:#003366; background:#cccccc; font-size:10px">
```

Second list:

```
<select id="2" name="ComboMunicipio" onchange="ExecMunicipio()" style="color:#003366; background:#cccccc; font-size:10px">
```

My code trying to retrieve text and value from the first list:

```
estados = soup.find(name="ComboEstado", id="2").find_all("option")
for estado in estados:
    print(estado.text, estado['value'])
```

(this only works for the if i use onlye soup.find(id="2"), but since both lists have this attribute, i don't think this is a good identifier)

The message i received:

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>   ----> 1 estados = soup.find(name="ComboEstado" ,id="2").find_all("option")
>         2 for estado in estados:
>         3     #nomes e codigos dos estados
>         4     print(estado.text, estado['value'])
>
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'

Also already tried to use this:

```
soup.find("name"="ComboEstado", id="2")
```

And received this:

> File "", line 1
>       estados = soup.find("name"="ComboEstado", id="2").find_all("option")
>                          ^ SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression

Also tried:

```
soup.find("ComboEstado", id="2")

soup.find("ComboEstado")
```

Both with the same first error.

Any idea what am i missing here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try identifying the lists like this:

```
list1=soup.find("select",{"name":"ComboEstado"})
list2=soup.find("select",{"name":"ComboMunicipio"})
```

Comment: No worries, if it solved your problem, please consider marking the answer as Accepted.